# live calculation go next step then back the number became what i set originally

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have done the code for the live calculation which means when the user entered data for all fields, the result will change accordingly. Then my page has a next button which let the user proceed to next step. If the user went to next page and wanted to go back to edit what he have entered, the result will be $0.00 but not the real result, unless the user reenter a value in an input box. Thus, what i want is just when user go back to the page, the result will remain what was showed.
Thank you for your time.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input').keyup(function(){
var $rincome = parseInt($('#textfield1').val());
var $rate = parseInt($('#textfield2').val());
var $age = parseInt($('#textfield3').val());
var $rage = parseInt($('#textfield4').val());
var rmoney = fv($rate/100,$rage - $age ,0,$rincome,0);
$('#rmoney').html(rmoney);
});
});
</script>
<form action="process.php" method="post" autocomplete="on">
<b>Income (SGD):</b>
<input type="number" id="textfield1" value="<?php echo $_POST['rincome'];?>" name="rincome" min = "0"  />
</p>

<p>
<b>Interest rate (%):
<input type="number" id="textfield2" value="<?php echo $_POST['rate'];?>"  name="rate" min = "0" step = "0.1"/> 
</p>

<p>
<b>Age:
<input type="number" id="textfield3" value="<?php echo $_POST['age'];?>" name="age" min = "0" max = "70"/>
</p>

<p>
<b>Life expectancy:
<input type="number" id="textfield4" value="<?php echo $_POST['rage'];?>" name="rage" min = "0"/>
</p>

<p>
<b>The total money you will have:$<span id = "rmoney">0.00</span>
</p>

<script>
function fv(r,n,p,pv)
{
var sum = pv;
for (var i=0;i<n;i++ )
{ 
    sum += sum*r + p;
}
return sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
}
</script>


<p style="text-align:center" style="font-size:160%">
<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Next"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</p>
</form>

<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION["rate"] = $rate;
$_SESSION["rincome"] = $rincome;
$_SESSION["age"] = $age;
$_SESSION["rage"] = $rage;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do two things:

1. **Store the input data in a SESSION variable**: When processing the form store the input data in a session variable. When you come back to the page, check if this session variable is set.. and if it is, use it to re-populate the form.
2. **On page load, run your calculation jQuery script once**: This is to ensure that if the form input is already pre-populated from Step 1 above, your page will show the calculated output from the start. I would put all the code in under your "keyup" section into another function and call that function on page load as well as on keyup.

Cheers!

---

To answer your additional questions:

Q) How should i tell the result to display used the stored data?
A) In the current file before displaying the form, check if $_SESSION variables are set. If they are set, make $_POST = $_SESSION. This will ensure your stored values are used.

Q) When the user click back, it will display what the user had entered in the input box, but the result is still 0 unless the user reenters at least one value?
A) This will get solved if you run the jQuery calculation on page load (in addition to on "Key up".

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do it.

Comment: Actually I already stored the data, how should i tell the result to display used the stored data?

Comment: i used echo in the html input type thus when the user click back, it will display what the user had entered in the input box, but the result is still 0 unless the user reenters at least one value.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but the result is still 0 unless the user reenters at least one value". What do you mean by "result" here?

Comment: <b>The total money you will have:$<span id = "rmoney">0.00</span>
The result means this. Sorry i do not know what this call thus i just say result. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Sessions. If you don't want to use sessions you can serialize data from the first step and keep it in the hidden field of your web form. When the user goes back to the previous step, you deserialize data for this step from the hidden field that you recieve by postback.

Comment: Thank you. I try to do it first.

Comment: I add the php part to store the data, but i still have no idea how to tell the result. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Update your question accoding to your modifications.

Comment: Look, you need to read about Sessions and how to work with them. http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php See example on this page. You need to write your data from $_POST to $_SESSION. And then restore your variables from $_SESSION